# Is a matplotlib figure a window?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is the term figure in matplotlib similar to window? So that making a new figure is like opening a new window?

```
# creates window with canvas?
plt.figure(1, (6, 6))
```

Comment: `plt.figure` returns the [Figure object](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure), a Python class. It has nothing to do with "opening a new window". Plotting a `Figure` may result in a new window showing the plot's image, but that depends on your environment.

Comment: `plt.figure(...)` creates a sort of canvas (hence, not a window), where you can place all sorts of graphical objects. ፨፨፨፨፨ In some cases (e.g., using the *magic* command `%matplotlib` in an IPython console) `plt.figure` ***immediately*** creates an interactive window, but in most cases no interactive window is shown, and everything lives, so to say, in memory until you commit the canvas content either to an interactive window (gracefully managed by Matplotlib) using `plt.show()`, or to a file, using `plt.savefig(...)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `plt.Figure` object, this is a canvas that you can plot onto. This does not automatically mean a window, however a window is displayed if you call `plt.show()`. If you save the `plt.Figure` object to a variable (e.g. `fig`) calling the `show` attribute (i.e. `fig.show()`) does the same, displaying that figure.

The main uses of `plt.figure` are to set the figure size and to set the DPI.